# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python-3.6, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, rhel7

```
WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-nu9_zlgc/numexpr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-nu9_zlgc/numexpr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-wheel-nu9_zlgc/numexpr/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-nu9_zlgc/numexpr/
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-tr7p7knw/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-tr7p7knw/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-tr7p7knw/numpy

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-wheel-nu9_zlgc/numexpr/setup.py", line 228, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/tmp/pip-wheel-nu9_zlgc/numexpr/setup.py", line 224, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 721, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 782, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 777, in fetch_build_egg
    return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
    raise DistutilsError(str(e))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python3.6', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpxhcxiwia', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  error: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python3.6', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpgvr79eoz', '--quiet', 'numexpr>=2.6.2']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Python Version 3.6.0, 
OS : Ubuntu 16 and 18 and 
OS : Rhel 7.3

Facing above error while running below commands

> > sudo python3.6 setup.py install 
> >     sudo python3.6 setup.py test

Comment: Try pip install numpy